# OS X El Capitan renames Windows volume on every boot by appending increasing numbers to the volume name

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I have installed Windows on a separate hard drive on my MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan. OS X is running on an SSD and Windows is on another physical hard drive. I named the other hard drive Windows partition as Windows.

On every boot of OS X, I am seeing the Windows partition listed as Windows X. X has now become 10 from 1 (I have rebooted my MacBook Pro ten times into OS X).

Why is this happening and how to prevent it? Because I have some links under OS X to files on the Windows drive they become obsolete with every reboot.